# Drush, post receive hooks and git branches/tags

Tags: 7, drush, version-control

I am stuck with a nagging issue in our deployment systems

- drush version 5.7
- git version 1.7.7
- Drupal 7.x

We currently have a bare git repository (consisting of drush makefiles) on the production server that fires off a post-receive hook to recursively build our Drupal multisite structure with drush make when it receives new data via a push from our local machines.

Everything works very swimmingly until a project in the makefiles contains either a git **tag** or **branch** in the definition. Then, the post-receive hook triggered build fails with :

> > git://github.com/[account]/[repo].git.
> >     DOWNLOAD_ERROR: Unable to check out tag 7.x-1.01. -- build forced  [warning]

Even more interesting : if I run the build on the production server locally or via a remote SSH command, the build succeeds. The problem only arises if it is run from a post-receive hook from a remote git push.

Verbose output offers no more information.

I can only assume that the post-receive hook system in git does not store/carry over an environment variable that is required for a drush to perform a two-step git operation on the single project. Is this a known issue?

I recognize this hurdle can be avoided by defining the project in the makefile as a 'get' download and providing the github download URL (instead of using the git functionality). Being pedantic, however, I'd like to narrow down where the problem is, and report it as a bug if appropriate.

I can repeat this on a fresh install.

But has anyone run into this? Solutions would be welcomed with elation.

Comment: Is your environment the same between the working (ssh) and non-working (git post-receive hook) cases?  Check your PATH, permissions, etc.; the error message rings no bells with me.

Answer (score 1):

Your tag `7.x-1.01` could be the problem ... In most Drupal projects the tag would be `7.x-1.1` (Without the zero)